# R433A SAW Resonator

Tags: transmission

I have one of those wireless weather sensor things that stopped transmitting.  Inside is one of those ubiquitous R433A SAW resonators that transmit on 433.92MHz.  I've verified that the board it's on is getting V+ and Data, so clearly problem is on the transmitter board itself.  So the question is, are those R433As known to go bad often?  (Often when something goes bad, someone will say, "Oh, trying replacing that first, it's usually the problem.")